# PHP Include Issue - Two includes don't work?

Tags: php

I've been having issues with my PHP include function. So can anyone explain to me why this would work...

//testfile1.php

```
    <?php 
        include 'file1.php';
    ?>
```

//testfile2.php

```
    <?php 
        include 'file2.php';
    ?>
```

but this will NOT work..

//testfile.php

```
    <?php
        include 'file1.php';
        include 'file2.php';
    ?>
```

Is there anyway to include the second file within the main file? I'm suppose to streamline two php files into one main file and run that. (All files are on the same directory and can 'see' each other no problem.)

Comment: You should be able to include, that is absolutely no doubt what so ever. What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: You're code makes no sense at all you just include `file1.php` and `file2.php` for what do you have the files `testfile1.php` and `testfile2.php` ?

Comment: what error you getting?

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: this could be an issue with file locations. If the include path is not absolute it is relative to the main file. you can use `getcwd()`  to find out what directory you are working from to figure out the correct relative paths.

Comment: what is your error message? please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your include statements to include_once. Look for includes within your included files and change them also.

If file1.php also includes file2.php itself, and file 2 had a function declaration, you could be re-declaring a function with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're overlapping include with files which are probably being included twice or not at all. In this case you need to use either

`include_once()` instead of `include()`

You can also use

`require_once()` instead of `include()` //use this option if the include is required

Comment: *Looks like you're overlapping include* OP doesn't include files anywhere multiple times or do I miss something here?